# Javascript regex involving zeros after the decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal-point

What would be the javascript regex to determine whether the digits after the decimal point are only zero and the number of zeros after the decimal point is greater than two?

Some test cases:

```
8 -> false
8.0 -> false
8.00 -> false
8.000 -> true
8.0000 -> true
8.00001 -> false
```

Comment: Does each string contain one number like this or is this rambled in larger text?

Comment: one number only - please note that, as shown in the first test case, the decimal point may not be necessary.

Comment: Can you show us something you're tried?

Comment: So you only want to match strings that do have a decimal point followed by all `0`?

Comment: @hwnd and the zero count must be greater than two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off your comments, if `0.000` is legal and you want to reject mutliple leading zeros along with only zeros after the decimal point being greater than two, the following should work for you.

```
/^(?!00)\d+\.0{3,}$/
```

**Explanation**:

```
^         # the beginning of the string
(?!       # look ahead to see if there is not:
  00      #   '00'
)         # end of look-ahead
 \d+      #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
 \.       #   '.'
 0{3,}    #   '0' (at least 3 times)
$         # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uA9lP1/4)

Comment: Thanks. This works great. Perhaps a slight improvement is rejecting expressions like 000.000 (\d+ allows one or more zeros before the decimal point) Of course, now I'm wondering if 000.000 is a number or not, but in my case your regex is good enough for me.

Comment: Would `0.000` be considered a match?

Comment: Only 0.000 should be legal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex which matches to a `.` and then 3 or more 0s at the end of the string.

```
/\.0{3,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var pattern = /^\d+\.0{3,}$/; // Regex from @hwnd

function checkDigits(digits) {

    var result = pattern.test(digits);

    return result;
}

alert(checkDigits("5.000")); //Returns true.
```